# SQL Server CE count group by

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I want to create a SQL query that will do the counting for me instead of in the razor code, I want to calculate the amount of distinct dates in my database.

I found that SQL Server CE does not support `count(distinct column_name)` and instead using `group by` would be the solution, but for some reason I could not make it work, what am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT COUNT(date) as date 
FROM Test 
GROUP BY date
```

This simply counted every date in my database and not the distinct ones when writing it out like the following

```
var totalcount = 0;

foreach (var c in db.Query(query))
{
    var ttotalcount = c.date;
    totalcount += ttotalcount;
}
<a>@totalcount<a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**
Your query is asking for the counts of each distinct date.  If you want to know how many of those you have you need to sum them up.  You can do this be nesting your query with a SUM query.  Then use an additional column defulted to "1", to allow to sum up the number of rows (which should be your distinct dates).  Also date can be a reserved word.  You might want to try and avoid using that as a column name.

```
SELECT SUM(New_Row) as dateSUM from (
   SELECT COUNT(date) as dateCount, 1 as New_Row FROM Test GROUP BY date
) a
```

Comment: gave me error on `Invalid column name "dateCount".` :/

Comment: if you run just the `SELECT COUNT(date) as dateCount FROM Test GROUP BY date` do you get the same error? Also, does it return a column named dateCount?

Comment: no, but the result is then all the dates in the database :/ @jradich1234

Comment: I'm trying to help you determine where the Invalid column name is coming from.  My question wasn't to solve the op but to determine if the aliasing was working correctly.

Comment: I see! not sure actually! @jradich1234

Comment: Also where was the error in the SQL or the C# code?  I've noticed that I forgot to alias the SUM result.

Comment: `c.dateSUM` resulted in all dates, and `c.dateCount` gives error on `<a>@c.dateCount</a>` in the foreach loop! @jradich1234

Comment: by "resulted in all the dates" do you mean that it gave you a number that matched the record count of the TEST table?

Comment: it gives a total value of all the dates in the database, which atm is 78, but many of them are the same, I know that its atm only 31 different dates, so its not selecting only 1 of each @jradich1234

Comment: I see,  then just add a "1" to the nested query and sum that.  That should allow you to sum up the number of rows returned by the sub query, which should be your distinct count.  Example updated...

Comment: That worked, thank you very much for the troubles haha! Cheers @jradich1234

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
SELECT COUNT(date) as [date] 
FROM Test 
GROUP BY date
```

`Date` is a reserved word, need to add `[]`

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing SQL with the three usages of date. I am assuming that the original field is named date. I am also assuming that each record has the date field populated.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as numDates FROM Test GROUP BY date
```

Comment: looping out `c.numDates` resulted in the same as my original query :/